# Fieldset markdown syntax

Tags: markdown

Given a textual representation of a field set in a markdown document:

```
Author: Robert Heinlein
Title: Stranger in a Strange Land
ISBN Number: 9780425058336
```

I would like to convert this to an HTML table (below is a sad approximation)

```
--------------------------------------------
| Author      | Robert Heinlein            |
--------------------------------------------
| Book        | Stranger in a Strange Land |
--------------------------------------------
| ISBN Number | 9780425058336              |
--------------------------------------------
```

---

**The question is:**  Is there any markdown language extension that will support converting a simple readable text fieldset into an aligned HTML fieldset?

---

I am guessing this would probably be a headerless table.

I have reviewed some of the markdown table extensions (MultiMarkdown, Pandoc, etc..) however the textual representation seems to be an overkill for an aligned field set.

This is for use in  multipart/alternative text/HTML e-mail system so it's important that the text reader doesn't feel like they are reading an exotic layout.

Suggestions for a single-pass PEG parser syntax are welcome.

## Update:

I am thinking of developing this fieldset syntax as a pegdown parser block plugin:

```
) Author     : Robert Heinlein
)              (also known as the "dean of science fiction writers")
) Book       : Stranger in a Strange Land
) ISBN Number: 9780425058336
```

It's concise, readable and it doesn't seem to conflict with any other markdown dialects.  At least pegdown and the on-line processors I could find don't see to mind.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a pandoc definition list, and style it so that the fields are aligned? (You'd have to use style tags for this to work well in mail.)

Comment: That is the best idea so far.  I'd like to keep the field name and value on the same line in the markdown text, but the definition list is the closest representation.

Answer (score 1):

with [markdown extra](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/#def-list) you have Definition Lists.

```
Author
: Robert Heinlein

Title
: Stranger in a Strange Land

ISBN Number
: 9780425058336
```

makes

```
<dl>
    <dt>Author</dt>
    <dd>Robert Heinlein</dd>

    <dt>Title</dt>
    <dd>Stranger in a Strange Land</dd>

    <dt>ISBN Number</dt>
    <dd>9780425058336</dd>
</dl>
```

You can create a 2-column table with css

> dl dt {clear: both; float: left; font-weight: bold; width: 20%;}
>   dl dd {float: right; width: 78%; margin-left: 0}

Answer (score 0):

**markdown has no method to do the trick**, the only way is to inject a classical HTML code into your markdown file.

example:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Personalia:</legend>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Author  </td>
      <td>Robert Heinlein</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Book </td>
      <td>Stranger in a Strange Land</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ISBN Number  </td>
      <td>9780425058336  </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</fieldset>
```